# Ohm symbol in latex

Tags: symbols

I have gone through symbol charts of latex and could not find how to put an ohm symbol. Like `\theta`, `\omega`, is there some command for ohms symbol?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage{siunitx}`. After that just input as `\si{\ohm}`. If you want to use a specific value it is better to mark it up like `\SI{1}{\ohm}`.

Answer (score 30):

Just use `\Omega` since ohms symbol is uppercase Greek letter omega.

Comment: @JouleV While I do agree that using the math mode symbol `$\Omega$` isn't the ideal way to get an Ohm symbol, please note that `$\Omega$` _is_ upright. I find the downvote (if it's from you, otherwise sorry) a wee bit exaggerated.

Comment: @campa I rarely downvote any first post, so don't worry. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/7qvKjoj.png).

Comment: This is a reasonable answer.  I don't understand the downvote. +1

Comment: It is an essential complement to the accepted answer, as not all publishers allow `siunitx` to be loaded.

Answer (score 8):

Since the ohm symbol is just the non-italic greek omega letter, you can as well use the command `\textOmega` from the `textgreek` package, which *is* in the large [symbols table](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).