# There's a mistake with this table and I don't find the problem

Tags: tables

When I try this table there's a problem at the end of the first row and I don't know how to fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{A}
\author{AA }
\date{November 2018}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}



\begin{document}


\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth { | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[r] | }
 \hline
 l(cm) & V(V) & I(A) & R(\Omega)\\
 \hline
 4  & 0,020  & 1,70 & \\
 \hline
 8  & 0,051  & 1,70 & \\
 \hline
 12  & 0,077  & 1,70 &8\\
 \hline
 16  & 0,102  & 1,70 & \\
 \hline
 20  & 0,127  & 1,70 &\\
 \hline
 24  & 0,152  & 1,70 &\\
\hline
\end{tabu}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Omega` will only work in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

The `tabu` package is broken, don't use it. In this case you can just use an ordinary `tabular`.

Your first error tells you `Missing $ inserted`, because `\Omega` is a math mode command, you can't use it in text mode. In general, you should make a clear distinction in your code what is math and what is not. For example, the variables in your table head (`l`, `V`, `I` and `R`) should all be math.

For the numbers and units in your table (and anywhere else in your document), I recommend using the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. From your use of `,` as a decimal marker I guess that you are writing in German, so I chose that setting in the MWE below. (It is conveniently irrelevant if you use `,` or `.` in the input to `siunitx` macros, though. If you don't get the numbers with `,` from some other program, I would always prefer to type `.` in the code since that's compatible with pretty much any program you may want those numbers to interact with.)

For tables, I recommend using the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. Have a look at its documentation and maybe [this post](http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html) for why that's a good idea.

Now, here's how I would typeset your table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2] S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=1]}\toprule
    {\(\displaystyle\frac{l}{\si{\centi\meter}}\)}  &   {\(\displaystyle\frac{V}{\si{\volt}}\)} &   {\(\displaystyle\frac{I}{\si{\ampere}}\)}   &   {\(\displaystyle\frac{R}{\si{\ohm}}\)}  \\\midrule
    4   &   0.020   &   1.70    &   \\
    8   &   0.051   &   1.70    &   \\
    12  &   0.077   &   1.70    &   8   \\
    16  &   0.102   &   1.70    &   \\
    20  &   0.127   &   1.70    &   \\
    24  &   0.152   &   1.70    &   \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

If you don't like the fraction notation in the table head, you can of course use something like `{\(l\) in \si{\centi\meter}}` or `{\(l\) [\si{\centi\meter}]}` instead. In tables with a lot of columns the fraction notation can be advantageous due to its slenderness, though.

Answer (score 1):

(As has been pointed out [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494922/theres-a-mistake-with-this-table-and-i-dont-find-the-problem#comment1249441_494922) by [schtandard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48973/schtandard)) `\Omega` -- like any other greek letter macro -- needs to be run in math mode. In this case you want it to be "inline", so just wrap it in single $, like `$\Omega$`

So your full line would be

```
 l(cm) & V(V) & I(A) & R($\Omega$)\\
```

N.B. If, as I suspect, you are using this as an Ohm symbol, there is [a related question with some suggestions for displaying it in a more typographically correct way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/ohm-symbol-in-latex) (*i.e.* upright, rather than italic).

Comment: Thank you very much, already solved!