# Greek Omega (Ohm) in running text ACM Whitelist conform

Tags: greek, letters, acm

I am trying to get a Greek omega letter as an Ohm sign in the running text for my paper. I found a solution using `siunitx` or `textgreek` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/ohm-symbol-in-latex). Unfortunately, the packages are not on the whitelist of ACM that can be found [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/whitelist-of-latex-packages). Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the `\ohm` command from `siunitx` if it is on the list. You'll get both  an upright Ω and a correct spacing with the `\SI` command

Comment: As mentioned in my question the package is not on the list.

Comment: It has the old `SIunits` package, though... and that should offer an upright Ω somewhere.

Comment: If you are restricted on packages, can you use simply `\ensuremath{\Omega}`?

Comment: \ensuremath{\Omega} workes perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably want to do `\newcommand{\ohm}{\ensuremath{\Omega}}` to (a) reduce typing and (2) allow you to easily make any necessary adjustments to formatting later.

Comment: I should update whitelist. `siunitx` is definitely ok

Comment: Make sure that µΩ and mΩ work the way you want if you switch to math mode, since that introduces some extra spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without any packages at all, by taking the symbol from the (default) OT1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}       % Not needed since 2020
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Not needed since 2018

\providecommand\textOmega{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\symbol{"0A}}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2125}{\textOmega} % Ohm symbol

\begin{document}
550~µΩ--600~\textmu\textOmega
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern font sample]

In math mode with `amsmath`, you’d wrap this in `\textnormal`.  If you want the units to stay upright even when the text is italicized, add `\upshape` between `\fontencoding` and `\selectfont`.

Comment: These are precisely the kinds of things I'm trying very hard to understand: picking one character from a font, the various encodings and what they actually mean, 8 bit, unicode, etc. Where are these things documented and explained?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL The font tables are in [the LaTeX Font Encoding Guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf), and `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` is defined by `inputenc` and documented there.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL The reference to the text font commands is [LaTeX2e Font Selection](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf)

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL But for a good user-friendly document, you might go to the `[LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) or Overleaf’s documentation.

Comment: Okay some of these I'd seen before, but the second one you link to looks to be what I'm looking for.